# jQuery slideup casuing multiple slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking to use jQuery to slide an element down, wait, then slide it back up.

When I use the following code, it slides down fine, but then when sliding back up it seems to slide up and down multiple times.

HTML:

```
<div id="area">
    <div id="summary"><p>hello summary</p></div>
    <div id="dropdown">
        <div class="item"><p>hello item</p></div>
        <div id="functions"><p>hello functions</p></div>
    </div>
</div>

<p><a href="#" id="test_add">TEST ADD</a></p>
```

jQuery:

```
$("document").ready( function () {
    $("#test_add").bind("click", add_item_annimate)
})

function add_item_annimate() {
     $("#dropdown").slideDown("fast").delay(1500).slideUp("fast");
}
```

Not really sure why this is happening.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: You should try to add event to your `add_item_animate` function and then `event.preventDefault()` as maybe its firing on multiple elements. Otherwise its never bad practise.

Comment: Try about event.preventDefault(), i tried your code in Mozilla 33, Chrome 38 with Jquery 1.6-2.1 and i canḉt reproduce your error. Do you have any other calls to that function in your code or its just only that?

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because of animation queue, for clearing it you can use the [`stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method:

```
$("#dropdown").stop(true).slideDown("fast").delay(1500).slideUp("fast");
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should do the trick!

```
$("document").ready( function () {
            $("#test_add").click( function(){
                $("#dropdown").slideUp("fast").delay(1500).slideDown("fast");
                 //SlideUp and slideDown can be switched.   
            });
            });
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/xcm8n1s3/

Answer (score 0):

You didn't have anything preventing a user from clicking on "TEST ADD" multiple times before the animation completed.

```
if ($("#dropdown").is(':animated')) {
    return false;
}

$("#dropdown").slideDown("fast").delay(1500).slideUp("fast");
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z1kwburq/) of the working demo.